# Special/reserved characters do not appear correctly encoded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, character-encoding, special-characters

I am trying to create a webpage that has some official contest rules in French.

The page was built using Bootstrap 3.2. (Using the default bootstrap download ...no special changes.)

No matter what I try, I cannot get the French accent characters or other special HTML characters (such as 'registered trademark') to appear correctly in all browsers.

When I view the file in a browser, it fails in both Chrome and Internet Explorer.
Only FireFox shows the correct characters, while the others show an invalid character placeholder.

I have tried the friendly code, numberical code and hex code... but have had no luck.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Here is a sample of my 'test page':

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Bootstrap with French Characters</title>
<link href="../../css/updated/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<p>RÈGLEMENT OFFICIEL</p>
<p>R&Egrave;GLEMENT OFFICIEL</p>
<p>R&#200;GLEMENT OFFICIEL</p>
<p>R&#xC8;GLEMENT OFFICIEL</p>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the code above highlights my attempts with all the different character options.

If I remove the link to bootstrap.min.css, then everything works right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the approaches fail and there is no other style sheet affecting the situation, then some font in your system must be faulty. The Bootstrap CSS defines:

```
body { font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
```

If the system has a font named “Helvetica Neue”, for example, and this font contains information about character support, saying that “È” is supported, but it actually isn’t, then we probably see a small rectangle. The font information might be broken in a manner that works differently in different browsers.

So check out “Helvetica Neue” and “Helvetica” in your system and inspect what characters they contain.

(The *first* approach, using “È” as such, which is generally best, fails to work if the document is not actually UTF-8 encoded. But encoding issues do not affect the way that character or entity references like `&Egrave;` work.)

Comment: Thanks! It does seem to be a font-family problem. Great suggestion!